# <div> content is not loading in <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-url="demo-page">
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="" width="100%" height="300">
        </iframe>   
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="div-content">
            <h1>Panel responsive</h1>
            <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the push display mode, the right panel reveal. To make this responsive, you can make the page re-flow at wider widths. This allows both the panel menu and page to be used together when more space is available. This behavior is controlled by CSS media queries.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#iframe1").attr('src','#div-content');
    });
</script>
```

[Here my Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/1437/)

Here my problem is that I want to load only `<div>` content in `<iframe>`. But in my case when I load `<div>` content in `<iframe>` then extra content is loaded in `<iframe>`.

If someone have any idea about this problem then please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#iframe1').contents().find('html').html($('#div-content').html());
```

or

```
$('#iframe1').contents().find('body').html($('#div-content').html());
```

Comment: thanks it working fine.But i also want to know the reason that what is problem with my code.

Comment: In your approach, you are setting the source attribute of iframe which should be a file.

Comment: Can't i use with this way if not then why ?`$("#iframe1").contents().find("#div-content");`

Comment: Yes if cross domain policy is not violated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#iframe1').contents().find('body').append($('#div-content'));
  });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/1440/)